# How to display products by categories using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a database with two tables named categories and products. I want to display products by categories.

Like

```
Category 1
         -Product 1
         -Product 2 
Category 2
         -Product 1
         -Product 2
```

But, my code returns Category name with each product. Like

```
Category 1
         -Product 1
Category 1
         -Product 2
Category 2
         -Product 1
Category 2
         -Product 2
```

Here is my code attempt:

**Model**

```
function NestedProducts()
{
    $sql = "Select C.c_name, P.productname 
        From categories C left join products P on C.id = P.category_id 
        Order by C.c_name";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $data['productsbycategory'] = $this->Model->NestedProducts();
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach($productsbycategory as $row) : ?>
   <div>
      <h4><?php echo $row['c_name']; ?></h4>
          <div>
          <h6><?php echo anchor('method/'.$id, $row['productname']); ?></h6>        
         </div>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update your query using `group_concat` and `group by` clause and you will get comma separated values which you can simply explode on `comma`

```
$sql = "Select C.c_name, group_concat(P.productname) as productname 
        From categories C left join products P on C.id = P.category_id 
        group by C.c_name
        Order by C.c_name";
```

Note: Not Tested

Comment: Getting Error *Array to String Conversion*, but how to convert it, it's array of array

Comment: Post your `print_r($your_array)`

Comment: Can you explain me plz how to apply it. explode(',', anchor('cms/article/'.$row['a_id'], $row['heading']));

Comment: But where did you posted your array

Answer (score 0):

You need to create sub array of products with category as their respective key.

```
function NestedProducts() {
    $sql = "Select C.c_name, P.productname 
        From categories C left join products P on C.id = P.category_id 
        Order by C.c_name";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $products = array();
        if ($query->num_rows()) {
          foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $products[$row['c_name']][] = $row;
          }
        }
        return $query->result_array();
}
```

And in view:

```
<?php foreach($productsbycategory as $categoryName => $row) : ?>
   <div>
      <h4><?php echo $categoryName;?></h4>
      <?php foreach($row as $product) : ?>
          <div><h6><?php echo anchor('method/'.$row['id'], $row['productname']); ?></h6></div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Model should be :

**Model**

```
function NestedProducts()   
{     
  $sql = "SELECT C.c_name, P.productname    
FROM categories C    
LEFT JOIN products P on C.id = P.category_id    
ORDER BY C.id";     

$query = $this->db->query($sql);    

return $query->result_array();    
}
```